# How can I use multiple property files in spring with the same name

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a plugin-based system where plugin-modules are added to the classpath.
Each module can have specific configuration for that module to add configuration to the application.

Such a plugin roughly looks like this:

- some `@Component`s, using properties from the platform/parent application
- some `@Component`s using properties from its own configuration

However, how do I ensure that:

1. the properties are loaded and usable, and
2. that the property file names don't clash with other property files in other plugin-modules.

I know I can probably do something with `@PropertySource("my-properties-file.yml")`, however, on the classpath may be several plugin-modules, all having a `my-properties-file.yml`

Comment: I had a similar problem once. I solved this by adding the module name to the file name to create unique file names. But I don't enforce this rule programmatically.